# How to get the button in FrameLayout for NavigationDrawer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I m new to NavigationDrawer, the code below is working.

But how to get the button inside the homeLayout.axml which is inflated as indicated in HomeFragment.cs after the below code.

```
   ft.Add(Resource.Id.HomeFrameLayout, new HomeFragment());
   ft.Commit();
```

1) I need to add eventHandler to this btn : btnProducts in homeLayout.axml
- where to add below code
 what I need to add to setup code to get the btnProducts and add event for this button??

```
  SetContentView (Resource.Layout.????);
  Btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnGM);
  Btn.Click += Btn_Click1;
```

--- UI:

Main Layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:minWidth="25px"
      android:minHeight="25px"
      android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">
   <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/layout_main"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">
   <include
      layout="@layout/app_bar" />
   <FrameLayout
     android:id="@+id/HomeFrameLayout"
     android:minWidth="25px"
     android:minHeight="25px"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
   android:id="@+id/nav_view"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="start"
   app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
   app:headerLayout="@layout/headerdrawerlayout" /> </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

-- Code for main UI

```
public class NaviDrawerActivity : AppCompatActivity
 {

    private SupportToolbar toolbar;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;     

   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

      SetContentView(Resource.Layout.NaviDrawer);          
      drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);

      //--- Init toolbar
      toolbar = FindViewById<SupportToolbar>(Resource.Id.app_bar);

      SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.app_name);
      SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
      SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

     //--- Attach item selected handler to navigation view

     var navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
     navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected;

     //-- Create ActionBarDrawerToggle button and add it to the toolbar

    var drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, Resource.String.open_drawer, Resource.String.close_drawer);
    drawerLayout.SetDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.SyncState();

     //--load default home screen

      var ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
       ft.AddToBackStack(null);

       ft.Add(Resource.Id.HomeFrameLayout, new HomeFragment());
       ft.Commit();
   }


  //---define custom title text

  protected override void OnResume()
  {
       SupportActionBar.SetTitle(Resource.String.app_name);
       base.OnResume();
  }
```

-------------HomeFragment.cs

```
 class HomeFragment: Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);           
        }

     public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState)
        {
          View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.homeLayout, container, false);
          return view;
       }
    }
```

----------homeLayout.axml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ff46a2fd"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnProducts"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="#307FC1"
            android:text="merchant"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your HomeFragment.cs in the OnCreateView method add the following (between the declaration of view and the return statment):

```
var btnProducts = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnProducts);
btnProducts.Click += btnProducts_Click;
```

Then add the method for your click event (somewhere in your HomeFragment class):

```
public void btnProducts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Action you want to take upon button click
}
```